# Cross relationship between models (high i lov level)

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I have a few models and relationship. People belongs to city, city belongs to region, region belongs to country. How can I display every people from particular country.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your models have relations defined already. You could use whereHas() and the model relationships in dot notation to get all the people of the city of the region of the country you're intersted in.

```
$people = People::whereHas('city.region', function($query) use ($countryId) {
        return $query->where('regions.country_id', $countryId);
    ->get();
```

Comment: You can use `whereHas('city.region',`.